# What is the difference between SVM and GMM classifier

Tags: machine-learning

What is the difference between support vector machine and Gaussian mixture model classifiers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Gaussian mixture model is a special case of a mixture distribution, which is a simple way of combining probability distributions.

However, the SVM does not make any assumptions. It is just a function, which depends on the distance of a data point from another point/plane. Som there is absolutely no probabilistic assumptions.

Comment: Thank you. Can you give some examples where both are used for different purposes